# Only let certain user connect to an alternate RDP Port

Tags: windows-7, networking, remote-desktop

Ok, Why ?

There is some users on the local network that are accessing an remote desktop servers

But some of these user also required an way to connect to the remote desktop but from internet. That alternate port is forwarded to the internet

The way I added the second listening port is this way http://jvhconsulting.wordpress.com/2010/11/16/adding-or-changing-remote-desktop-listening-port/

Is there a way to let Only certain user access the alternate port using the original windows "Remote Desktop Connection"

Perhaps there is a way to select witch user have the right to connect to port 3389 and witch user can connect to port 3399  Perhaps something like local serurity policy have a setting some where.

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: ok, I'm not sure what you mean by port, but Transport layer ports (TCP/UDP) cannot be restricted to "users" only to packet characteristics occurring at the transport layer or lower. if you want to filter access by criteria on a higher level, you will have to leave authentication and authorization up to the application itself, in this case RDP.

Comment: Yes, this is what i mean. Is there a way rdp can let only certain users to connect to it alternate port that it listening.

Comment: no, because ports don't know what user is trying to connect, and RDP doesn't care what port you're coming in on. You could probably setup IP restrictions for the port in your firewall(s), so only certain IPs are able to access the port, but that means any user from that IP can get in, and if an allowed user moves someplace else (or their IP changes), they won't be allowed in.

Comment: unfortunately, you probably can't run two instances of the RDP service, with separate configuration. and you can't firewall based on user. the best bet would be to allow your approved remote users to VPN into your network, and control it there, but that involves some infrastructure. perhaps you can implement some form of Port Knocking: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_knocking

Comment: @FrankThomas I am currently thinking of an other way, That might work actualy..    I am currently playing around with localgroup polcy editor and saw that when a user is loggin in. we can lauch script.  That made me think..   What do you guys think of lauching a script in the script to check if user is an user that is alowed and if not kick log him off  Whould that be secure enough ?

Comment: @FrankThomas And thanks for the idea of port knocking never hear of that before.  But the thing is on the client side it would be very nice that it stay the same login steps.

Comment: if you are just worried about keeping a few employees from getting caught up on work from outside the office, then your script will probably be sufficient, but I don't believe it would not stop an actual attacker for long.

Comment: @FrankThomas "you can't firewall based on user", windows supports [firewalling based on user](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759078.aspx), however it only works on "secure" connections that contain user data for the channel.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain, ok, thats interesting. I would not characterize it as network firewalling since it happens are layer 7, and is not identified by any characteristic of the network traffic, but it is neat to have those kinds of access controls.

Answer (score 2):

A better approach to this (and the method Microsoft recommends you do) is not expose a RDP port to the outside at all. Instead expose a VPN port that the user can connect to, then once on the VPN connection they can connect to the RDP server.

This will allow you to restrict which users have VPN access separate from which users have RDP access.

If you don't want to set up a VPN the other option is to use a [Remote Desktop Gateway Manager](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725706.aspx) that sits on the border between the public internet and your internal machines. You can set up rules for the RD Gateway limiting [which users can connect](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731544.aspx) and what machines the users are [connecting to](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732204.aspx).

Comment: Yea, But I can't change the way people connect right now,.   But there is in place a system that send an email to us and create a firewall rule if too much fail login occur

Comment: Hum!,.   Il have to read on that,. ( Remote Desktop Gateway Manger )   Look promising. And could maybe be acceptable change for users to login,.   The only thing is that some user have to connect localy so i hope that gateway dont need to be connected stricly from internet.

Comment: The Gateway approach, if set up fully, will work without people needing to do any extra steps. The box for "Automatically Detect RD Gateway settings" is on by default in the remote desktop client. (Show more options -> Advanced -> Settings)